# How to use ajax to load default values into form

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<form id="PersonForm">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>

Postal Code: <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal"> <br>

Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br>

Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> <br>

<input type="submit">

</form>

<a href="frontend.html">Refresh</a> 
<a id="InsertDefault" href="">Insert Default Data</a> 
<br>

<ul id="errors"></ul>
<p id="success"></p>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<?php

// Return JSON default data if requested
if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'default')
{
  $defaultData = array('name' => "Jane",
                       'postal' => "L5B4G6",
                       'phone' => "9055751212",
                       'address' => "135 Fennel Street");

  echo json_encode($defaultData);
```

How would I use the default values array and load the default values when I click insert default data using ajax? I created a click fucntion for insertdefault but am stuck there.

Comment: Why ajax? You can load a result as you mentioned with ajax, but then you can use js to populate those fields when the user clicks that button or calls that function. Maybe there is something I'm missing and you need to do something else in the middle of the process?

Comment: I just need to use AJAX to request the the javascripts that have the all the values.

Comment: Where is you AJAX function?

Comment: Just added below a possible solution to make that work. Use ajax to update something that require server or backend work async. But once the data is in script side, you can handle input fields with jQuery or JS. You don´t need to submit the form to add data to the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing that using the response of the ajax in json or set default values with the link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#InsertDefault').click(function(){
    $('#name').val('Jane');
    $('#postal').val('L5B4G6');
    $('#phone').val('9055751212');
    $('#address').val('135 Fennel Street');
  });
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var jsonObjFromAjax = {
      "name":"Jane",
      "postal":"L5B4G6",
      "phone":"9055751212",
      "address":"135 Fennel Street"
  };
  $('#name').val(jsonObjFromAjax.name);
  $('#postal').val(jsonObjFromAjax.postal);
  $('#phone').val(jsonObjFromAjax.phone);
  $('#address').val(jsonObjFromAjax.address);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The script prints the form and the data when requested, you would need to print only the data when requested, with an if, or a separate file.
And for the AJAX part, if you have no problem using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("your-file.php?act=default", function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $("#"+key).val(val);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First generally you load default values if they exist with PHP

`<input type = "text" value="<?php if (isset($var)){ echo $var ; } else { echo ''; }">`

If you want to load them with JS(jquery)

`$("input").each(function(i,v){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
           for(i=0; i < result.length; i++) { 
                 if ( result[i]['name'] == name ){
                       $(this).val(name);
                         break;
                      }
               }
       });`

Untested of the top of my head